# Transformar um comando SQL em Lambda ou Stream do Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Estou iniciando no Java 8 e gostaria de transformar o comando em SQL abaixo em uma função lambda:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Correspondencia c, (SELECT entidadeOrigem, MAX(m1) 
similaridadeMaxima FROM Correspondencia WHERE m1 <> 0 GROUP BY 
entidadeOrigem) r WHERE c.entidadeOrigem = r.entidadeOrigem AND c.m1 = 
r.similaridadeMaxima
```

Criei a Classe `Correspondência` com `getters` e `setters`.

```java
public class Correspondencia {
    
    int codigo;
    String nome;
    String entidadeOrigem;
    String EntidadeDestino;
    double m1;
    double m2;
    double m3;
    double medMax;
    double dem;
    
    
    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEntidadeOrigem() {
        return entidadeOrigem;
    }
    public void setEntidadeOrigem(String entidadeOrigem) {
        this.entidadeOrigem = entidadeOrigem;
    }
    public String getEntidadeDestino() {
        return EntidadeDestino;
    }
    public void setEntidadeDestino(String entidadeDestino) {
        EntidadeDestino = entidadeDestino;
    }
    public double getM1() {
        return m1;
    }
    public void setM1(double m1) {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }
    public double getM2() {
        return m2;
    }
    public void setM2(double m2) {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }
    public double getM3() {
        return m3;
    }
    public void setM3(double m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }
    public double getMedMax() {
        return medMax;
    }
    public void setMedMax(double medMax) {
        this.medMax = medMax;
    }
    public double getDem() {
        return dem;
    }
    public void setDem(double dem) {
        this.dem = dem;
    }
}
```

Quero transformar a query SQL em uma expressão lâmbda ou stream do Java 8.

Criei uma lista de `Correspondencia`:

```java
List<Correspondencia> cor = new ArrayList<>(); 
cor.add(new Correspondencia(41,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0,0.14,0.04,0.23,0.08")); 
cor.add(new Correspondencia(11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0,0.19,0.21,0.19,0,0.12)); 
cor.add(new Correspondencia(31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0,0.36,0.5,0.41,0,0.25)); 
cor.add(new Correspondencia(01,"PaperAbstract_Abstract","PaperAbstract","Abstract", 0,0.33,0.45,0.32,0,0.22));
```

Agora quero filtrar o curso com Lambda ou Stream de acordo com a query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Correspondencia c, (SELECT entidadeOrigem, MAX(m1) similaridadeMaxima FROM Correspondencia WHERE m1 <> 0 GROUP BY entidadeOrigem) r WHERE c.entidadeOrigem = r.entidadeOrigem AND c.m1 = r.similaridadeMaxima
```

Porém, ficaria mas claro o retorno da query do sql para

```java
List<Correspondencia> cor = new ArrayList<Correspondencia>();

cor.add(new Correspondencia(41,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0.14,0.04,0.23,0.08));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(22,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0.15,0.04,0.23,0.08));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(22,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0.36,0.04,0.23,0.08));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.19,0.21,0.19,0.,0.12));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.25,0.21,0.19,0.,0.12));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.37,0.21,0.19,0.,0.12));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0.36,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0.38,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0.37,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(32,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.36,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(01,"PaperAbstract_Abstract","PaperAbstract","Abstract", 0.33,0.45,0.32,0.,0.22));
cor.add(new Correspondencia(01,"PaperAbstract_Abstract","PaperAbstract","Abstract", 0.37,0.45,0.32,0.,0.22));
```

que me retornaria como resultado o maior valor de m1 agrupado pela entidadeOrigem:

```java
22,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0.36,0.04,0.23,0.08
11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.37,0.21,0.19,0.,0.12
31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0.38,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25
01,"PaperAbstract_Abstract","PaperAbstract","Abstract", 0.37,0.45,0.32,0.,0.22
```

Answer (score -1):

Edição: Você precisa usar a biblioteca Stream do Java. Pelo resultado da sua query você retorna a Correspondência com maior M1.

O comando `filter(x -> x.getM1() != 0)` é o equivalente ao `where` do SQL. Para usar o filtro você cria um objeto seguindo a definição lambda (nesse caso, o objeto x) e usa uma expressão que deve retornar `true`ou `false`.

O comando `.max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getM1()))` é bem parecido com o `max` do SQL, só que ele espera um objeto do tipo `Comparator`. A API do comparator disponibiliza um método para escrever comparação usando lambda, só que ao invés de um boolean, o comparator espera um valor para poder comparar - neste caso, passamos o valor de m1.

Segue abaixo um código de exemplo de como implementar isso usando Stream.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class JavaFiddle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Correspondencia> cor = new ArrayList<Correspondencia>();

        cor.add(new Correspondencia(41,"Paper_Organization","Paper", "Organization",0,0.14,0.04,0.23,0.08));
        cor.add(new Correspondencia(11,"email_hasanemail","email", "hasanemail",0.19,0.21,0.19,0.,0.12));
        cor.add(new Correspondencia(31,"Review_Reviewer","Review","Reviewer",0.36,0.5,0.41,0.,0.25));
        cor.add(new Correspondencia(01,"PaperAbstract_Abstract","PaperAbstract","Abstract", 0.33,0.45,0.32,0.,0.22));

        Correspondencia maxM1 = cor.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getM1() != 0)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getM1()))
            .get();

        System.out.println(maxM1);
    }
}



class Correspondencia {
    int codigo;
    String nome;
    String entidadeOrigem;
    String EntidadeDestino;
    double m1;
    double m2;
    double m3;
    double medMax;
    double dem;

    public Correspondencia(int codigo, String nome, String entidadeOrigem,
        String entidadeDestino, double m1, double m2, double m3, double medMax,
        double dem) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.entidadeOrigem = entidadeOrigem;
        this.EntidadeDestino = entidadeDestino;
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.m3 = m3;
        this.medMax = medMax;
        this.dem = dem;
    }


    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEntidadeOrigem() {
        return entidadeOrigem;
    }
    public void setEntidadeOrigem(String entidadeOrigem) {
        this.entidadeOrigem = entidadeOrigem;
    }
    public String getEntidadeDestino() {
        return EntidadeDestino;
    }
    public void setEntidadeDestino(String entidadeDestino) {
        EntidadeDestino = entidadeDestino;
    }
    public double getM1() {
        return m1;
    }
    public void setM1(double m1) {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }
    public double getM2() {
        return m2;
    }
    public void setM2(double m2) {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }
    public double getM3() {
        return m3;
    }
    public void setM3(double m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }
    public double getMedMax() {
        return medMax;
    }
    public void setMedMax(double medMax) {
        this.medMax = medMax;
    }
    public double getDem() {
        return dem;
    }
    public void setDem(double dem) {
        this.dem = dem;
    }
}
```

Resposta original:
A classe em si não explica muito sobre o seu contexto... Onde precisará ser modificado na verdade é onde você utiliza a consulta... assumindo que você usa Hibernate, o código ficaria mais ou menos assim (assumindo que `sess` é sua sessão do Hibernate):

```java
List correspondencias = sess.createCriteria(Correspondencia.class)
    .add( Restrictions.ne("m1", new Integer(0)) )
    .list();
```

Você pode obter mais informações na documentação do Hibernate: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/querycriteria.html

Para uma lista de comandos que podem usar nos Restrictions (o que seria equivalente ao WHERE no SQL) veja o link a seguir: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Comment: O problema é que está retornando apenas o maior valor de m1.                                           
E  o que eu preciso é que retorno do maior valor de cada item repetido de m1 pela entidadeOrigem.